# How to regenerate the lockfiles for Flutter repo?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I got [an error](https://logs.chromium.org/logs/flutter/buildbucket/cr-buildbucket/8766333470118445361/+/u/Android_Views_Integration_Tests/stdout) for my PR to Flutter that instructs to regenerate the lockfiles.

First, I tried to follow instructions in the error, but was getting failures of different types, most likely related to my local configuration of gradle.

Then I discovered [the script in flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/dev/tools/bin/generate_gradle_lockfiles.dart), that seems to be doing exactly what I want.

I removed my local installations of gradle, ran the script as instructed in the file and got error:

```
polinach-macbookpro3:flutter_dev polinach$ find . -type d -name 'android' | dart dev/tools/bin/generate_gradle_lockfiles.dart
Usage: find . -type d -name 'android' | dart dev/tools/bin/generate_gradle_lockfiles.dart
If you would rather enter the files manually, just run `dart dev/tools/bin/generate_gradle_lockfiles.dart`,
enter the absolute paths to the app's android directory, then press CTRL-D.

Processing examples/hello_world/android
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/polinach/_/flutter_dev/examples/hello_world/android/app/build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 457ms

  Command: /Users/polinach/_/flutter_dev/examples/hello_world/android/gradlew :generateLockfiles
#0      exec (file:///Users/polinach/_/flutter_dev/dev/tools/bin/generate_gradle_lockfiles.dart:128:5)
#1      main (file:///Users/polinach/_/flutter_dev/dev/tools/bin/generate_gradle_lockfiles.dart:99:5)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:33)
#3      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Is it a bug in script or I am doing something wrong?